# Prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Basically I'm converting all my statements in my class file to prepared statements. After reading over the php.net manual, I still cannot see where or what my error is.

In this particular function I am getting the profile of a user by the users ID.

Any help fellas?

```
    public function getProfile($id){
    if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =?")){
        $result->bind_param("s", $id);
        $result->execute();
        $result->bind_result($id);
        if($result->num_rows !=0){
            return $result->fetch();
        }else{
            return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what does this code do?  What does it return?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: P.S. your `$result->close();` will *never* be ran.

Comment: It returns a users profile information on the $_REQUEST of a users ID. And as of right now, no errors are being shown in my Apache error logs

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to `$id`, but returning the result of `return $result->fetch()` (a bool).

Rather do

```
if($result->num_rows !=0){
        $result->fetch();
       return $id;
    }else{
        return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
    }
```

Also, instead of doing a `SELECT *`, you may want to list out the fields of interest and bind them explicitly.

Comment: Ryan, what you're saying makes sense, but does not solve my problem

Comment: I've actually read in a few other places that SELECT * is very picky with prepared statements. Let me try listing the fields that I need and see a result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `bind_result` with `SELECT *`.  You need to either specify the fields in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT name, username
```

And specify each variable in the `bind_result`.

```
$result->bind_result($name, $username);
```

<sub>(Note that `$result->fetch()` just populates the variables from `bind_result`, it doesn't return the data, it returns a boolean.)</sub>

```
public function getProfile($id){
    if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT name,username FROM users WHERE id =?")){
        $result->bind_param("s", $id);
        $result->execute();
        $result->bind_result($name, $username);
        if($result->num_rows !=0 && $result->fetch()){
            return array('name' => $name, 'username' => $username);
        }else{
            return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Or use `get_result()` to get the entire row:

```
public function getProfile($id){
    if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =?")){
        $result->bind_param("s", $id);
        $result->execute();
        if($result->num_rows !=0){
            $row = $result->get_result();
            return $row->fetch_assoc();
        }else{
            return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JasonBassett: What do you mean by "none work"?  What gets returned?  What do you want returned?  How do you know they don't work?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done.

```
<?php

public function getProfile($id){
    if($result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =?")){
        $result->bind_param("s", $id);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();

        if($result->num_rows !=0){
            $result1 = $result->get_result();
            return $result1->fetch_assoc();
        }else{
            return array("error"=>"Profile-Not-Found");
        }
        $result->free_result();
        $result->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: to use num_rows you need to store_result()

Comment: Also, along with what everyone else has been saying, bind_result can not be used with select *

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
$result->bind_param("s", $id);
```

to

```
$result->bind_param("i", $id);
```

as I would have thought that an ID of something would be an integer (maybe the unique ID of your record?)

Comment: For mysql it doesn't really matter